# Using R plot in Latex output - not finding saved .png

Tags: graphics, r, knitr, png

I am trying to create a plot in R and use knitr and latex to print that plot to a pdf. I think I am taking the correct steps:
1. save plot as .png in same folder as .tex file
2. write this into the latex file as includegraphics
3. run the knitr

However, the program is not recognizing/finding my recently created plot .png even though I checked that it is there in explorer.

This is my code in R to create the .png that seems to successfully create the .png file in my working directory (which is also where the .tex file is):

```
png("hab_pie.png", height=400, width=400)
bp <- ggplot(aoi_HabTerr2, aes(x="", y=acres, fill=habitat)) + geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity")
bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
dev.off()
```

This is the relevant code that is in my .Rnw document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}     %for headers,footers
\usepackage{underscore}  %needed if any text has underscores
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\geometry{letterpaper, top=0.45in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{hab_pie}

\end{document}
```

I am getting this error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `hab_pie' not found.
```

And when I look in the folder, the file is present under the same name:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a wider MWE, with preamble ?

Comment: No, no, no!  knitr does not work in that way at all. Try these steps: (1) Make a working LaTex "Hello"  document (2) Save it with `.Rnw` extension  (2) insert after "Hello"  some working R code (e.g. `2+3`) delimited between  lines with `<<>>=` and `@`  (4) Open  it  with  Rstudio and push the "Compile" button.  Finish. You should have already a PDF with the R ouput, in this case, with "Hello" and  the result of the sum (5). The same if the R code is a plot. BTW,  better use  PDF formats (not PNG) for the R graphs in a LaTeX document.

Comment: @Fran - my R script is long and complicated with many variables/actions.  It is my understanding that I should not be writing all of this into the LaTex document.  But, instead, that if I have my R script call my LaTex document with knitr, then this handles it better. Eventually (it works right now, but not with all steps yet) it will be a fully functional script tool in ArcGIS which is meant to pull in layers from ArcMap, do a bunch of stuff, and output a PDF report. So I also need the code to be in R language so that ArcMap can handle it.

Comment: @sztruks I added the preamble and a bit more of the code. I'm not sure that anything else is relevant. I have other bits of code that incorporate variables from my R script and a table from my R script, as well as a chunk that pulls in an already saved .png file as a figure. All of these actions are working fine.

Comment: Can you try to give the image a name without special characters like `_`? Which tex engine do you use to compile? `pdflatex` or something else?

Comment: @samcarter - thank you!  it was a the special character that was causing the issue.

Comment: @mmoore Why not? The main purposes of `knitr` are (1)  literate programing: the same file is able to R programming and typesetting the results and discuss them. It can manage a entire book about statistics without problem  (2) reproducible research: with the source file, anyone can trace how everything was exactly done,  and  more important (3) save your time:  free you from include/update manually the results and make mistakes doing this. `;)`